# New User gets a blank page by entering from Facebook canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-login

every time when a new user (or a test user) access my app from facebook (canvas) he gets an empty page.

If the user navigate direct to the app it works. Than the user get the permission dialog from facebook and have to grant the requested permissions. After this the user can use the app from facebook canvas or direct from *www.MY_APP.com*.

What I know about the problem:

1. It occurs for a new/test user who **did not grant the permissions** for the facebook app
2. It occurs only on direct access from facebook canvas.

I think the permission dialog can't be shown from facebook but I don't know why.

My app is developed with ruby rails and uses OmniAuth 1.4.0 for login.

The gem-file

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'koala'
```

The routes.rb:

```
match '/canvas'                  => 'sessions#facebook_canvas'
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create',             :as => :create_session
```

The omniauth.rb initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET,
       {:scope   => 'email, user_groups, friends_groups, read_stream, read_friendlists, friends_likes, friends_status, offline_access',
        :display => 'popup',
        :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}} }
end
```

The sessions_controller :

```
# modified sample code from OmniAuth to handle the signed request
def facebook_canvas
   session[:canvas]         = true
   session[:signed_request] = params[:signed_request]
   # we just redirect to /auth/facebook here which will parse the
   # signed_request FB sends us, asking for auth if the user has
   # not already granted access, or simply moving straight to the
   # callback where they have already granted access.
   #
   # we pass the state parameter which we can detect in our callback
   # to do custom rendering/redirection for the canvas app page
   redirect_to "/auth/facebook?signed_request=#{request.params['signed_request']}&state=canvas"
end

# create a session, when the user 
def create
   auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
   user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
   if user  
      session[:fb_token] = auth["credentials"]["token"] if auth['provider'] == 'facebook'     
      redirect_to_target_or_default root_url #, :notice => "Logged in successfully."
      redirect_to confirm_abg_path(:user => user.id)
   else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login or password."
      redirect_to root_url
   end
end
```

I hope anyone can help me.